# ef-Code-First one-to-many optional delete throws exception:primary key value cannot be deleted

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-many

I have looked and found no solution to what seams to be a simple thing, i got 3 entities When i try to delete the *City* or *District*  i get this exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The primary key value cannot be deleted because references to this key still exist. [ Foreign key constraint name = FK_dbo.User_dbo.District_DistrictId ]
```

What am trying to achieve is :
when i delete a city all children districts to be deleted, but not users.
when i delete a district only the district is deleted.
When i delete a user only the user is deleted.

1. City

   - A City can have 0 - N number of Districts and Will Cascade On Delete
2. District

   - A District is Required to have a City and has Optional 0 - N Users
3. User

   - A User can have Optional 0 - 1 District

**The entity User**

```
public class User
{
  public Guid UserId { get; set; }

  public virtual District District { get; set; }
  public Guid? DistrictId { get; set; }
 }
```

**The entity City**

```
public class City 
{
    public Guid CityId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<District> Districts { get; set; }
}
```

**The entity District**

```
public class District 
{
    public Guid DistrictId { get; set; }

    public City City { get; set; }
    public Guid CityId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
//EntityTypeConfiguration
   HasRequired(d => d.City)
            .WithMany(c => c.Districts)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.CityId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true); 

    HasMany(d=> d.Users)
            .WithOptional(u=> u.District)
            .HasForeignKey(u=> u.DistrictId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I tried placing this configration in the user Mapping but nothing change same error

```
HasOptional(u => u.District)
            .WithMany(d => d.Users)
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.DistrictId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Also am using Sqlce4 and EF6 and the [Generic Unit of Work & Repositories Framework](http://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/)

Thanks for the help

Regards

Comment: Check your schema and see where this FK_dbo.User_dbo.District_DistrictId constrain is defined. Maybe you dont need it there then update model to remove that from there. I think your model is defining too many relationships like User with 1 district is alright and then defining it in District with N user might not be needed or other way around. You need to grab this from constraint and see if you need that or not.

Comment: I  use code first FK_dbo.User_dbo.District_DistrictId is a key generated in the sqlce databse keys i dont know if its even possible to delete it, also the configuration  mapping for the user was just to test if it works but still error shows up.

Comment: I recomment you take out both mappings then run your code and try delete. it should work. This may require you to delete database and seed it again but will clear some doubts. Then add one relationship and do the same if it deletes or not. Then add the other and remove first so you would know which one is causing it. This way you can help all of us here understand the scenario as well and learn in process what is actually happening with keys. You dont need to delete constrains from DB if you are using EF code first migrations. just remove keys from model to update and add new migration.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set the `DistrictId` foreign key of the `User` to `null` in order to avoid the constraint violation when you try to delete a `City` or a `District`. EF won't do that automatically if the related `Users` are not loaded into the context.

To delete a district you can do it like so:

```
// "Include" because you need the users to nullify their FKs to the district
var district = context.Districts.Include(d => d.Users) 
    .SingleOrDefault(d => d.DistrictId == someDistrictId);
if (district != null)
{
    // "Remove" will set the FKs of the LOADED users to null
    context.Districts.Remove(district);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

To delete a city:

```
var city = context.Cities.Include(c => c.Districts.Select(d => d.Users))
    .SingleOrDefault(c => c.CityId == someCityId);
if (city != null)
{
    context.Cities.Remove(city);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Cacsading delete will care about deleting the districts here. However, I am not sure if in this case the `DistrictId` of the loaded users will be set to `null`. If it doesn't work you have to do it manually:

```
var city = context.Cities.Include(c => c.Districts.Select(d => d.Users))
    .SingleOrDefault(c => c.CityId == someCityId);
if (city != null)
{
    foreach (var district in city.Districts)
        foreach (var user in district.Users.ToList())
            user.DistrictId = null;

    context.Cities.Remove(city);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, thought EF was intelligent enough to deal with a simple task such as this.
So had to clear the districts too not only the city, here is how i finally got it to work using this repository library

```
  var city = _unitOfWork.Repository<City>().Query()
            .Include(c => c.Districts.Select(d => d.Users))
            .Filter(c => c.CityName.Equals(cityName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            .Get().FirstOrDefault();

        if (city != null)
        {
            var districts = city.Districts.ToList();
            for (var i = districts.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var users = districts[i].Users.ToList();
                for (var j = users.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    users[j].DistrictId = null;
                    users[j].ObjectState = ObjectState.Modified;

                    _unitOfWork.Repository<User>().Update(users[j]);
                }
                districts[i].Users.Clear();
                _unitOfWork.Repository<District>().Delete(districts[i]);
            }
            _unitOfWork.Repository<City>().Delete(city);
```

sucks but it works

Comment: Ended up having to do it this way too.  Pretty ridiculous.